# SQL Server : problems with Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a database with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I want to perform a very simple SQL request:

```
SELECT 
   [Date], [Price]
FROM 
   [mydatabase].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE 
   [Date] = CAST('2011-06-17 06:00:00' AS smalldatetime)
```

and I get the following error message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Of course `Date` type is smalldatetime, but still having problems.

Can anybody help me with this?

[image: Table looks like]
[image: Datum is smalldatetime]

Comment: What's the type of `[Date]` column and what if you cast to datetime instead of smalldatetime?

Comment: Type is like you see smalldatetime. If i cast it as date then i have no results.

Comment: Well then directly compare like `Where [Date]='2011-06-17 06:00:00'`. No need of casting I believe.

Comment: This ISO date format is not unambiguous for the legacy date datatypes and is interpreted according to the date settings of the login (derived from its default language). Try removing the dashes. `'20110617 06:00:00'`

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, i changed it in the properties of the server(under standard language, it was german now english), restarted the server service but still same problem.

Comment: And what is `Datum` field then (is it `Date` from your query)?

Comment: It is the default language of **the SQL Server login** not the server (set in management studio by expanding the logins node and finding the relevant one) but best to use an unambiguous format for the string literal as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

try casting to datetime instead of smalldatetime and change date format

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Price]
  FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[Table]
  Where [Date]=CAST('06/17/2011 06:00:00' AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: Doens't work. Same Error message. Tried it first without cast but no help.

Comment: oh then look at you table, [Date] column is not a date

Comment: It's 'smalldatetime' ? I don't understand, what you are meaning. Sorry.

Comment: No, doesn't help. Also with casting to datetime.

Comment: @FacebookUDE try the new answer ;)

Comment: That isn't unambiguous either. See http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp

Comment: Sorry i had to Leave my Computer now, the only difference i see is that you used / instead of -  this time. I will try this asap.